# Use Cases of JavaScript Timer Events Before Page Load

Tags: javascript, timer, dom-events

What are the typical use cases of JavaScript timers before a page is loaded?

When inspecting loading of Amazon with Chrome's developer tools, I can see several timers fired before the `load` event. The corresponding function calls of these timers are time-consuming. (For 8 timers, execution of corresponding functions took ~50ms each.)

In contrast, I don't see timers fired before the `load` event in some other websites such as Google Maps.

A screenshot of a portion of things that happen before `load`:

[image: A screenshot of a portion of things that happen before load]

Comment: What "timer" events are you describing? Could we get a screen shot to better understand what you're describing?

Comment: Screenshot added @TheDembinski